# JBOSS cannot find module for driver

Tags: oracle, module, jboss, wildfly

`standalone.xml`:

```
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/myDB" pool-name="myDB" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="false">
                    <xa-datasource-property name="URL">
                                jdbc:oracle:thin:@...
                    </xa-datasource-property>
                    <xa-datasource-property name="User">
                            ...
                    </xa-datasource-property>
                    <xa-datasource-property name="Password">
                            ...
                    </xa-datasource-property>
                    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    <driver>oracle</driver>
                    <xa-pool>
                            <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                            <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                            <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>
                            <no-tx-separate-pools>true</no-tx-separate-pools>
                    </xa-pool>
                    <validation>
                            <valid-connection-checker
                                    class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker" />
                            <stale-connection-checker
                                    class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker" />
                            <exception-sorter
                                    class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter" />
                    </validation>
                </xa-datasource>



                <drivers>
                    <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
                        <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
```

`/modules/system/layers/base/com/oracle/ojdbc6/main/`

contains `ojdbc6.jar` and `modules.xml`

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

But I get:

```
14:33:32,797 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] 

    (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
        ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
        ("jdbc-driver" => "oracle")
    ]) - failure description: "WFLYJCA0115: Module for driver [com.oracle.ojdbc6] or one of it dependencies is missing: [com.oracle.ojdbc6]"
```

Comment: did you copy the files as root perhaps and forgot to chown to the relevant user?

Comment: Also, in my notes I have  name="com.oracle"> withouth the ".ojdbc6" perhaps try that in modules.xml

Comment: omitting the `.ojdbc6` did not make it. also i did `chmod 777` on `modules.xml` and `ojdbc6.jar` but still no success :(

Comment: Location and names of the modules looks good. What looks fishy is the xa-datasource-class. In the drivers you have the wrong one. Move `xa-datasource-class` from `xa-datasource` to `driver`. Maybe also try to follow this [guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuration_guide/datasource_management#example_oracle_xa_datasource) and try it from scratch with cli scripts

Comment: @wirnse so I changed it to `                    <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.ojdbc6">
                        <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>` But still no success. I will read the guide you have referred to

Comment: I have found out, that the same exact configuration runs correctly on windows, but on mac the error mentioned in the question appears...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to:

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1384153

The file needs to be called `module.xml` instead of `modules.xml`. This fixed my issue. But on Windows it also works for `modules.xml`. Only on Mac this problem is appearing....

Answer (score 1):

The correct path is:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/modules/com/oracle/ojdbc6/main/
```

Comment: still no success

Comment: I have found out, that the same exact configuration runs correctly on windows, but on mac the error mentioned in the question appears...